# Via ajax called php file outputs an echo only the last time it is called

Tags: php, ajax, echo

Like the title says, I have a php file with an echo command in it. The file gets executed several times via ajax and through debugging I see, that the echo command is in fact executed each time. The output on the other hand is, that only the last call of echo really outputs html/text.

I thought it might have to do with caching and used flush() after the echo call. Didn't help. Any thought about what could go wrong here?

I don't bother to post any code as it really just is an echo of a div.

Comment: Do you want to display every echo statement in your html page? If so, instead of using `$(Element).html(Response);`, use `$(Element).append(Response);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are assigning the XHR object to a global variable.

Have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572013/1696923